# Rails 3 and mongoid: How would you about sorting / grouping collect to display as a 2 dimension table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, group-by, mongoid

I have  User model with many fields and I would like to display a 
table as a matrix of 2 of those fields: 
- created_at 
- type 
For the created_at I simply used a group_by as so:

```
(User.where(:type => "blabla" ).all.group_by { |item| 
item.send(:created_at).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }).sort.each do | 
creation_date, users|
```

This gives me a nice array of all the users per creation_date, so the 
lines on my table are ok. However I want to display multiple lines, 
each representing the sub selection of the users per type. 
So for the moment, I am performing one request per line (per type, 
simply replacing the "blabla").

For the moment it's ok because I have 
just a few type, but this number will soon increase a lot more, and at 
this will not be efficient I am afraid.

Any suggestion on how I could achieve my expected results ?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general answer here is to perform a [Map / Reduce](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce). Generally, you do not perform the map-reduce in real time due to performance constraints. Instead you run the map-reduce on a schedule and query against the results directly.

Here's a primer on [map-reduce for Ruby](http://kylebanker.com/blog/2009/12/mongodb-map-reduce-basics/). Here's [another example](http://markembling.info/2010/11/using-map-reduce-in-a-mongodb-app) using Mongoid specifically.